# Creating dynamic schema using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm very new to Node js and Mongoose module. I'm trying to create a schema, where there are some required fields and some others can be dynamic.

I have used `strict` to `false`. My code looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/ets',function(err)
{
    if(err) throw err
})

var Schema = mongoose.Schema
var Tasks = new Schema({vmProfile:String}, { strict: false });
mongoose.model('Task',Tasks)

var Task = mongoose.model('Task')
var task = new Task()
task.vmProfile = "required value"
task.otherKey = "something"
task.save(function(err)
{
    if(err) throw err;
})
```

when I run this , I get only the `vmProfile` saved, not `otherKey`, the DB looks like this:

```
{ "vmProfile" : "required value", "_id" : ObjectId("53364a5a5cd71a76122f0a8a"), "__v" : 0 }
```

where I'm making the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Mongoose [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict):

> NOTE: Any key/val set on the instance that does not exist in your
>   schema is always ignored, regardless of schema option.

You can set the value when the model instance is created:

```
var task = new Task({'otherKey', 'some value'});
```

You could also put the ad-hoc values under a [mixed](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema-mixed-js) subdocument type as well.

Comment: Thanks. But as a novice in node programming, which one is better option to choose? I guess for mixed type, I should have a key, which can take up any values.

Comment: It's more of a business logic and database schema question rather than a mongoose question. It's not Node specific really unless the question is whether to use Mongoose or the  MongoDB driver directly.