# How to create Mongodb schema dynamically using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a table dynamically in mongodb using a Mongoose schema, Node.js and Angular for example.

The basic way to make a schema is to create a model explicitly in Node.js like this:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const postSchema = new Schema({
    title: { type: 'String', required: true },
    content: { type: 'String', required: true },
    slug: { type: 'String', required: true }
});

let Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

Is it possible to create this schema dynamically by using the user input from an Angular frontend?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating dynamic schema using mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726972/creating-dynamic-schema-using-mongoose)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Sure it's possible...** - suggesting using [express](https://npmjs.org/express) as server framework:

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { Router } from 'express';
const router = Router();

router.post('/newModel/', createNewModel);

function createNewModel(req, res, next) {
  const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
  // while req.body.model contains your model definition
  mongoose.model(req.body.modelName, new Schema(req.body.model));
  res.send('Created new model.');
}
```

**...but please be careful!** Opening a way for users to modify your database so easily is usually not a good idea.

**Update:** The format is exactly the same as the one you want to have in the paranthesis:

```js
{
  "title": { "type": "String", "required": "true" },
  "content": { "type": "String", "required": "true" },
  "slug": { "type": "String", "required": "true" }
}
```

Comment: Thnaks @noChance for your answer, But could u mention the form of  the JSON format sent by angular for exemple in req.Model ?

Comment: I tried to send this by postman : {
 "ModelName":"Test",
    "ModelContent":{
      "title": "{ type: 'String', required: true }",
      "content": "{ type: 'String', required: true }"
    }
}  but it gives me en error :TypeError: Undefined type `{ type: 'String', required: true }` at `title`

Comment: you JSON object is not valid, I tried to send it using Postman it gives a syntax error, can u help please ?