# What could go wrong if I let users to create their own MongoDB collections

Tags: database, mongodb, security, mongoose

I am in the process of building a basic no-code solution to build RESTful APIS that support CRUD operations on a MongoDB collection. Right now it is just a Proof of Concept project that I use internally with no external users.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56004918/how-to-create-mongodb-schema-dynamically-using-nodejs) on Stack Overflow the other day and I though that it could allow me to convert this little project into a SaaS concept.

Allowing users to create their own collections in MongoDB could be potentially insecure, but I couldn't think of any catastrophic consequence... Maybe the fact that malicious users can purposely create a collection that is horrible in performance? Or maybe the user could inject some references to other collections...?

Does having a separated Mongo database help to mitigate those attacks? Or could you give me more reasons why this is a bad idea?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can manage user and privilege (on database, collections, etc..) with mongo through access control

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/collection-level-access-control/

You can also create "capped collection" to limit the size of collections

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/

I don't know exactly how you can limit "user performance" but i'm interested if you find an answer :)